# Issues with twilio sms module in PhP

Tags: php, twilio

I am trying to test the twilio sms reminder library with a trial account I created for this purpose. The problem is that when I launch the file from my XAMPP "webroot" folder that also contains the "Twilio" folder I see nothing, just a blank page on Mozilla Firefox while on IE the error code 500 is up. Please find my code below thank you.

```
<?php

require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/openemr/twilio/Services/Twilio.php";

// Step 2: set our AccountSid and AuthToken from www.twilio.com/user/account
$AccountSid = "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy";
$AuthToken = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

// Step 3: instantiate a new Twilio Rest Client
$client = new Services_Twilio($AccountSid, $AuthToken);

// Step 4: make an array of people we know, to send them a message. 
// Feel free to change/add your own phone number and name here.

$people = array(
    "+14158675309" => "Curious George",
    "+14158675310" => "Boots",
    "+14158675311" => "Virgil",
);


// Step 5: Loop over all our friends. $number is a phone number above, and 
// $name is the name next to it
foreach ($people as $number => $name) {

    $sms = $client->account->messages->sendMessage(

    // Step 6: Change the 'From' number below to be a valid Twilio number 
    // that you've purchased, or the (deprecated) Sandbox number
        "+12057198157", 

        // the number we are sending to - Any phone number
        $number,

        // the sms body
        "Hey $name, Monkey Party at 6PM. Bring Bananas!"
    );

    // Display a confirmation message on the screen
    echo "Sent message to $name";
}
```

Comment: Check your PHP error logs, or change your setup to display PHP errors. What do the errors say?

Comment: Are you including the Twilio's PHP library files as $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/openemr/twilio/Services/ ?

Comment: I agree with @JamieBicknell, look at the error log, otherwise it is like find a needle in haystack

Comment: Check it out in the debugger and let us know what you find! https://www.twilio.com/console/dev-tools/debugger